# c:forEach inside primefaces(e.g. p:panelgrid) inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, panelgrid

I have to dinamically produce a list of tables. Each of these have a variable number of columns (with fixed rows).

To perform this I first put a `<p:panelGrid>` inside an `<ui:repeat>`: so I correctly produced a list of tables.

Then, to dinamically produce the columns, I tried put both an  `<ui:repeat>` or a  `<c:forEach>` inside the `<p:panelGrid>`. In the result I obtain no rows.

I written a  minimal example here. In the bean `testBackingBean`, I have defined (and initialized) the variable `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tables`. This is the xhtml that does not produce the expected results:

```
<ui:repeat var="table" value="#{testBackingBean.tables}">
    <p:panelGrid>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column >header of #{table}</p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>
        <p:row>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${table}">
                <p:column>#{row}</p:column>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
```

Noteworthy the header-row correctly converts `#{table}` into string. The problem is that I see no rows of data.

Also, if I use the `<table>` instead of the `<p:panelGrid>` everything work as excpected.

Also, I tried different permutations of `<c:forEach>` and `<ui:repeat>` with no succes.

So, how can I dinamically produce more tables (using prime-faces) and set a dinamical number of columns?

Thanks!

EDIT: I would like to use two `<c:forEach>`, but even with one only `<c:forEach>` I get an empty result. In fact if I try the following xhtml:

```
<c:forEach  items="${testBackingBean.tables}" var="tabella">
    current element: #{tabella}
</c:forEach>
```

then I get an empty result. (I know,this is a different question)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The transition from the XHTML source code to the generated HTML output is a two-step process.

1. First, during view build time, the XHTML source code is parsed and turned in a tree of Java `UIComponent` instances representing the JSF UI component tree, as available by `FacesContext#getViewRoot()`.
2. Then, during view render time, the JSF UI component tree produces HTML output and writes it to the HTTP resopnse, starting with `UIViewRoot#encodeAll()` method.

[Taghandlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagHandler.html) like all JSTL `<c:xxx>` tags, several JSF `<f:xxx>` tags and only a few Facelets `<ui:xxx>` tags run during view build time. [UI components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) like all JSF `<h:xxx>` tags, several Facelets `<ui:xxx>` tags and only a few JSF `<f:xxx>` tags run during view render time.

[The `<c:forEach>` is a taghandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jstl/core/ForEachHandler.java#ForEachHandler) and [the `<ui:repeat>` is an UI component](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#UIRepeat).

In other words, the UI components which are declared inside `<c:forEach>` are recreated multiple times in the JSF component tree based on `<c:forEach items>` during view build time which in turn individually produce each their own HTML output during view render time. The UI components which are declared inside `<ui:repeat>` are created only once in the JSF component tree during view build time which in turn are reused multiple times based on `<ui:repeat value>` to produce HTML output during view render time.

Your concrete problem is caused by the fact that `<ui:repeat var="table">` is only available during view render time, not during view build time. The `<c:forEach>` is basically retrieving a `#{null}` as value when it's about to run during view build time.

You can solve this by replacing the outer `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>`. Although I wonder if you couldn't better use `<ui:repeat><p:dataTable><p:columns>` instead.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try `<p:dataTable>` with dynamical columns. BTW, if I use two `c:forEach` then the  `panelGroup`s are not produced.

Comment: Now I see that `<p:dataTable>` wants a _single_ bean with  arrays of properties. Unluckly my data is structured as an array of beans, each with some properties.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation :)