# c:forEach (in JSF) is not showing the inside elements

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In a JSF2 framework I can't let the `<c:forEach>` working.

For instance, if I use the following xhtml:

```xml
<c:forEach  items="${testBackingBean.tabelle}" var="tabella">
    forEach element:<h:outputLabel value="#{tabella}"/>
</c:forEach>

<ui:repeat  value="#{testBackingBean.tabelle}" var="tabella">
    repeat element:<h:outputLabel value="#{tabella}"/><br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

then, only the `<ui:repeat>`'s results are rendered in the HTML.

I really don't know why, but unluckly I have to use the  `<c:forEach>` becouse I need to iterate inside a primefaces element. (see [c:forEach inside primefaces(e.g. p:panelgrid) inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697024/cforeach-inside-primefacese-g-ppanelgrid-inside-uirepeat))

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: You already have a fully qualified answer to your question in your old question. Do not repost questions if you are not satisfied with the answer you get. You should provide more details describing your actual problem instead.