# How to create p:treeNode with arbitrary components based on arbitrary node data objects

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Assue I have a class `DataObj`

```
public class DataObj implements Serializable {
  private Set<String> values;
  private String name;

  // default constructor, constructor to pass properties

  // getter and setter
}
```

and set an instance as data property of a `TreeNode`:

```
@ManagedBean
public ACtrl extends Serializable {
  private TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode(new DataObj(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a","b")), "some name"));

  // default constructor

  // getter for root
}
```

How can I create dynamic `p:treeNode`s which contain components based on the data property (and it's content), e.g. a checkbox for each string in `DataObj.values`?

The following example shows how to change content based on the type or value of `TreeNode.data`, but `c:if` and `c:forEach` don't work (I'm very sure they aren't supposed to because node should be `null` when they're evaluated):

```
<ui:composition 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  >
  <h:form id="form">
    <p:tree id="tree" value="#{aCtrl.root}" var="node" >
      <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
        <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"/>
        <p:spinner value="#{node}" rendered="#{node.getClass().getName() eq 'java.lang.Integer'}"/>
        <c:if test="#{node.getClass().getName() eq 'DataObj'}">
          <c:forEach items="#{node.values}" var="value">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{value}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{value.name}"/>
          </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
      </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>  
  </h:form>  
</ui:composition>
```

Please consider this pseudo code... I'm aware that it doesn't run or compile, but it eases the explanation of my problem and possibly the answers :)

Do alternative JSF component libraries or extensions exist to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `ui:repeat` is necessary (tried this before but didn't pay attention to the fact that `value` has to be "a List, array, java.sql.ResultSet, or an individual java Object",  but not a key set of map keys :) - need to add `.toArray()` in this case ).

```
...
<p:treeNode id="treeNode" >
  <ui:repeat var="key" value="#{node.type.aValue.keySet().toArray()}">  
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" value="#{node.type.aValue.get(key)}"/>
    <h:outputLabel for="checkbox" value="#{key}"/>
  </ui:repeat>  
</p:treeNode>
...
```

where `node.type.aValue` is a `Map<String,Boolean>`.

Useful:

- [c:forEach inside primefaces(e.g. p:panelgrid) inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697024/cforeach-inside-primefacese-g-ppanelgrid-inside-uirepeat)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/)